# Как примонтировать файловую систему с раздела "Microsoft LDM data"?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

Установил убунту 20,04 на ссд, но до этого стояла винда, еще есть ж.д. с файлами, как его смонтировать sda1

lsblk

```
loop0         7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop1         7:1    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop2         7:2    0 217.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop3         7:3    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1932
loop4         7:4    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
loop5         7:5    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/498
loop6         7:6    0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop7         7:7    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop8         7:8    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop9         7:9    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931.4G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  30.5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   977M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   207G  0 part /
```

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/files

```
mount: /mnt/files: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CC4ECC4F-9C55-42DE-A5FF-2DC08AC93CD5

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     34 1953262990 1953262957 931.4G Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557217/4733583) подробно описаны шаги по подключению диска с Microsoft LDM